# How to get command-line arguments using a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line-arguments

I have a set of file names whom I have to insert as command-line arguments while my bash script is running. Is there any way to give command line arguments using a separate file (like `"test.txt"`)?

Let's assume these are the files: `fileA`, `fileB`, `FileC`, `FileC`, `FileD`, and let's assume the bash script is `testBash.sh`

Comment: arguments are in test.txt file?

Comment: can you change the `testBash` file?

Comment: Hello Rahul, Yes arguments are in a test.txt file

Comment: Hello طاهر I can change the testbash.sh scriptطاهر

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes easily using `xargs`. assume `file` content is

```
A
B
```

and the bash script file `s` content is

```
echo $1
echo $2
echo $@
```

then :

```
cat file | xargs ./s

A
B
A B
```

Comment: Hello, طاهر Thank you very much for your help... :) you have clearly mentioned about how to do that.... :)

Comment: One should remember xargs can split an argument list to multiple invocations of the same command, at an arbitrary place. So it's not proper for long lists. (In practice, this is done near ARG_MAX, but this isn't guaranteed.)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, and `test.txt` contains a list of file names you want to pass to `testBash.sh`, you should be able to do something like this:

```
cat test.txt | testBash.sh
```